Creating Treemap in Plotly Express for inflation data
I'm struggling on how to create a treemap of inflation data.
Its to do with the hierarchy data and parent data.
I keep getting errors.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Read the data from the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('UKCPI2.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

# Create the treemap with the filtered data
fig = px.treemap(df, path=['parent', 'Series'], values='Contrib') # Ensure 'contrib' is the correct column name for your values
fig.show()

I keep getting errors


what is the error?

The errors I get is that when I load the plot I just don’t get the data displayed. There is nothing.
Is it way that the inflation data is structured. With the hierarchy etc?

Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, ie. edit your post and provide the data as code instead of a screenshot of the excel sheet. Also, having "nothing" in the output is different from having errors, if you got any error, copy/paste the error message, otherwise remove "I keep getting errors" and describe what happens (blank page ?, empty plot ?).
